# pfsense device freeze at a time load balancing airtel works fine

Tags: pfsense

We have 2 lease lines Tata and Airtel. Primary is Tata & Sec is Airtel If Tata down pfsense device freezes at a time load balancing airtel works fine but has been 192.168.1.1 not working.Anybody knows about his. Your help is greatly appreciated.